# How to reduce 'click' when using ES2 synth

Tags: logic-pro, synthesizer

I'm using ES2 in Logic to make basic bass/wobble tracks. Though, whenever I use it, I normally get a slight 'click' or 'pop' before each and every note that is played. Does anyone know how to reduce this..?

Comment: Im having the same issue, but with the specific synth ES P. It doesnt seem to have any of the mentioned effects, but the click sound at the beginning of each note is very disturbing.. Ive tried a bit back and forth on the different buttons.. without any luck. Any suggestions? Peace!

Answer (score 5):

I don't know for ES2 in particular (as I've not used it), but in other synthesizers this can mean that an oscillator waveform is not starting on a zero-crossing when the key is depressed. If this is the case, you have one of two immediate options:

1. Adjust the phase of the oscillator, or alternately, force the oscillator to always begin on a zero-crossing. Your synth will have to have one of these two features. I don't know if ES2 does.
2. Raise the attack time on the volume envelope to a few milliseconds, long enough for the click to be inaudible but for the sound to be mostly-instantaneous.

I've generally had good luck using the second method when making bass wobbles for dubstep-style music.

Answer (score 1):

The Envelope affecting something in the router and the env decay is set to very short so the effect (maybe Cutoff) sounds like a click because it just shoots up the cutoff very quickly and brings it back down.

Try bringing the env decay that affects the cutoff up, or lowering the router effect so the cutoff doesn't shoot up really high but maybe only half way.